# how to create AVD eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

my code run correctly on an external device but i cannot run it on AVD

my steps to create AVD is as follow :

1. create
2. select name "aavd"
3. choose 3.3" WQVGA (240x400 :ldpi) as device choose Android 4.
4. 4.4W - API Level 20  as a target
5. Choose ( armeabi-v7a) as a CPU/ABI

then I choose

- 512 RAM
- 16 VMheap
- 200 internal storage

then ok --> start --> lunch 
then run configuration --> select myAVD

now it take a very very long time to start AVD then it give me this msg "just a moment" 
then lunch cancel and give this message in logcat :

```
 [2014-12-20 23:23:18 - invitationCard] Android Launch!
 [2014-12-20 23:23:18 - invitationCard] adb is running normally.
 [2014-12-20 23:23:18 - invitationCard] Performing com.example.invitationcard.MainActivity    activity launch
 [2014-12-20 23:23:24 - invitationCard] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'aavd'
 [2014-12-20 23:23:53 - invitationCard] New emulator found: emulator-5554
 [2014-12-20 23:23:53 - invitationCard] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
 [2014-12-20 23:25:15 - invitationCard] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
 [2014-12-20 23:25:15 - invitationCard] Uploading invitationCard.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
 [2014-12-20 23:25:35 - invitationCard] Installing invitationCard.apk...
 [2014-12-20 23:27:41 - invitationCard] Failed to install invitationCard.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
 [2014-12-20 23:27:41 - invitationCard] (null)
 [2014-12-20 23:27:41 - invitationCard] Launch canceled!
```

so now my question is  : 
where is my error and how can i fix it !!?

my manifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.invitationcard"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
      <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainActivity2" >
    </activity>
      <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".BdActivity" >
    </activity>
      <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".weddingActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Graduation" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".b0" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".b1" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".b2" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".b3" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".b4" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".b5" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".b6" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".b7" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".b8" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".b9" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".b10" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".b11" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".b12" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".b13" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".b14" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".b15" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".w1" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".w2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".w3" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".w4" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".w5" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".w6" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".w7" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".w8" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".w9" >
         </activity>
         <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".w10" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".w11" >
                    </activity>

             <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".w12" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".w13" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".w14" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".w15" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".w16" >
    </activity>
        <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".g1" >
    </activity>
         <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".g2" >
    </activity>
         <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".g3" >
    </activity>
         <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".g4" >
    </activity>
         <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".g5" >
    </activity>
         <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".g6" >
    </activity>
         <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".g7" >
    </activity>
</application>

 </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using one of the pre-built AVD's.  You may also want to check to make sure that you set the minimum API level to that of your apps requirements.
I have also run across situations where my AVD was corrupt.  In order to fix this, close eclipse, delete the .metadata folder, then restart eclipse and import your project and recreate your AVD.

Comment: Okay so if you have already deleted the .metadata folder if you're using eclipse.  If you're using android studio - Idk.  But if you have deleted that folder, then I would change the API of your AVD to 21 rather than 20 since that is what your app is targeting.

Comment: Okay then try this. Start task manager and end the process that is called 'avd' or something consisting of 3 letters that is like that.

Comment: there is no process like this

Comment: Just so it is documented, the process is called 'adb'

Answer (score 0):

Start the emulator first before running the application.
You'll probably want to increase Heap Size too.

Comment: ok i started the emulator first already . :( 
and i increase the heap size but same error

Comment: The error you posted shows a new emulator is created. Change the configuration to run the application on a running AVD.